# ejecutar script javascript dentro de un div cargado con ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un index.php el cual contiene un div llamado contenido

en el cual cargo otro archivo listarusuarios.php  con el siguiente script

```
    function ajaxFunction() {
var xmlHttp;

try 
{  
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
return xmlHttp;
} catch (e) 
{

try 
{
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  return xmlHttp;
} catch (e) 
{

  try 
  {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    return xmlHttp;
  } catch (e) 
    {
    alert("Tu navegador no soporta AJAX!");
    return false;
    }}}
}




function Enviar(_pagina,capa)
{
var ajax;
ajax = ajaxFunction();
ajax.open("POST", _pagina, true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded");

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState==1){
        document.getElementById(capa).innerHTML = " Aguarde por 
   favor...";
             }
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {

            document.getElementById(capa).innerHTML=ajax.responseText;

         }}

ajax.send(null);

 }
```

y envio el contenido de listarusers.php a traves de un enlace

```
<a href="Javascript:Enviar('listarusers.php' , 
'contenido')">Enviar</a>
```

el archivo "listarusers.php" contiene un script para calendario en jquery

```
    dhtmlXCalendarObject.prototype.langData["es"] = 
{
    dateformat: "%Y.%m.%d",
    monthesFNames: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", 
  "Junio", "Julio","Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", 
  "Diciembre"],
    monthesSNames: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun","Jul", 
 "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Diz"],
    daysFNames: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles","Jueves", 
 "Viernes", "Sabado"],
    daysSNames: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sa"],
    weekstart: 1,
    weekname: "w"
};

var myCalendar;
function doOnLoad() 
{
    myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject(["cal_1", "cal_2", 
 "cal_3","cal_4", "cal_5", "cal_6","cal_7","cal_8","cal_9",]);
    myCalendar.setDate(new Date(2000,0,1,16,0));
    myCalendar.loadUserLanguage("es");
}
```

Parte Html de listarusers.php donde llamo al calendario sobre el input

El caso es que si cargo listarusers.php en el navegador, funciona correctamente, pero si lo envio al div "contenido" a traves de ajax , el calendario no funciona. He probado a declarar el script del calendario y el doOnLoad(); del body en el index.php  ya que se esta cargando sobre esa capa y asi como arrastra el css supuse que arrastraria tambien el JS pero parece que no.